# Replace inside quotes in string

Tags: powershell

I have a string with the following format:

```
$string = '123 test "replace here" 456 "windows 10" end'
```

I need to split the string with space delimiter, but keep quoted part as one unit. I've tried to replace space inside the quoted part, so it should be like

```
$string = '123 test "replace_here" 456 "windows_10" end'
```

But the `.Replace()` method works on all spaces. How can I use replace for quoted parts only?

Comment: Regex is the magic you are looking for: https://powershell.org/2013/08/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/

Comment: You want to use a regex replacement with a callback function that replaces spaces in substrings between double quotes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers imho the mark as duplicate doesnt really fit this time. The question differs to much, or rather to the problem statet here can be broken down to one simple `-replace` call with the correct regex.

Comment: @Paxz How? As long as there are just 2 words between the double quotes a simple regex replacement with backreferences would work, but what if the number of words varies? I think using a callback function would be the best choice here.

Comment: I just wanted to simplify the solution given that you have a static number of words / constant given scenario with `"word" "word"`. Sure, if you expand the scenario to more usecases, callback functions works better.

Comment: The OP didn't clarify how many spaces the double-quoted substrings may or may not contain, so I believe a general solution is the best we can suggest here.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the number of spaces could be different, in example I used only one space. I used regex `$String | Select-String '"([^"]+)"' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches.Value.Replace(" ","_")}`, that replaces the spaces. For saving this back to $string I need to use another foreach cycle?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to the question linked at the top of your question.